# How to configure release-drafter based on the commits not the merged pull requests

Tags: javascript, github, pull-request, release-notes

I'm going to integrate [release-drafter](https://github.com/toolmantim/release-drafter) to one of our repositories.
The integration is pretty straight forward. But my problem is that once we Squash and Merge a PR to our based branch (develop), we checkout a new branch called release/tagVersion (from develop branch) and create a new PR for it. Then we release our new build to staging as a feature release. 
Once the QA is successfully done in staging, we merge the corresponding PR for release/tagVersion to master.

The problem is that since in our workflow we need to create this release/tagVersion and a PR for that, once we merge it to master, the release-drafter is gonna show only the commits we made on this PR. Not the previous commits in our feature branch.

My question is that, is there any way that we can configure release-drafter in a way it logs the commits that are going to be merged to master and not only the most recent one?

```
1. checkout a new branch from develop named feature/ticketNumber-ticket-description
2. Create a PR for this feature branch
3. Squash and Merge it to develop branch and release it to staging
4. Checkout a new branch from develop (containing new codes) -> release/tagVersion
5. Create a PR for this release branch and fix the bugs here
6. Merge it to master.
```

I want release-drafter to put the commits we Squashed and Merged in the step #3. Not the one in #5.

Here is my release-drafter configuration file:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

name-template:  $NEXT_PATCH_VERSION
tag-template: $NEXT_PATCH_VERSION
template: |
  ### What’s Changed

  $CHANGES

no-changes-template: No changes
```

Comment: There's no solution at the moment. Check this GitHub issue to track the progress. https://github.com/release-drafter/release-drafter/issues/552